# notepad++ regex expression

Tags: regex, windows, registry, notepad++

I have the following problem. File contains records like this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.sometexthere\: "some.text.here"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.sometexthere\Content Type: "sometexthere/sometexthere"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\sometexthere.sometexthere\sometexthere: "{B571EB41-3BD6-405F-9CA7-DFA4B8D1564E}"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\sometexthere\sometexthere: "{F064F716-AEBF-4AAC-8FC4-1ED635A026BE}"
```

I want it to be replaced with:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.sometexthere]
@="some.text.here"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.sometexthere]
"Content Type"="sometexthere/sometexthere"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\sometexthere.sometexthere]
"sometexthere"="{B571EB41-3BD6-405F-9CA7-DFA4B8D1564E}"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\sometexthere]
"sometexthere"="{F064F716-AEBF-4AAC-8FC4-1ED635A026BE}"
```

Can you please help me to figure out two regex expressions to do that please.

Comment: Sorry, it is too unclear and broad. There is no regex that will match arbitrary registry paths in a safe way, you may only match those that you set specific requirements for. It is not clear if `simetexthere` is dynamic or not, and the rules for splitting are rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

You might try it in two steps with two replacements:

1. Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

   - Open Replace Dialog
   - **Find What:** `^((.*)\\([^\\]*):[ ]*"([^"]*"))`
   - **Replace With:** `[\2]\r\n"\3"=\4`
   - Check **regular expression**
   - Click Replace or Replace All

Now it should look as requested up to `@` like in the first line of your example. We need this second step:

2. Do a normal find/replace like this:

   - Open Replace Dialog
   - **Find What:** `^""=`
   - **Replace With:** `@=`
   - Click Replace or Replace All

As Wiktor already commented, that might or might not work. It depends on your data.